# Gsubing when we have multiple backslashes and/special characters

Tags: r, gsub

I have a string in which I want to get out the city, in this example it would be 'Elland Rd' and 'Leeds'.

```
mystring = "0000\" club_info=\"Elland Rd, Leeds\" Pitch=\"100x50\""
city = gsub(".* club_info=\"(.*),(.+)\.*", "\\2", mystring) #cant get this part to work
```

My theory behind getting the city is to search for everything after the comma and up until the backslash but I cant seem to get it to recognize the backslash

Comment: Hi Joe - great question - I edited it to streamline the question since all the stadium stuff was irrelevant for this specific question. This will hopefully fast track you getting some high quality answers, though apologies if I inadvertently changed your intent. Good luck!

Comment: FYI, there are no backslashes in your string, the `\"` is R's way of showing an embedded double-quote in a string when rendered to the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer `strcapture` to extract multiple patterns vice repeated `gsub`ing, how about this?

```r
strcapture('.*club_info="([^"]+),([^"]+)".(.*)', mystring, list(x1="", x2="", x3=""))
#          x1     x2             x3
# 1 Elland Rd  Leeds Pitch="100x50"
```

(It was not required to include the `Pitch=` in there, but I thought you might use it since it appears you're doing reductive `gsub`ing.)

FYI, `x2` here has a leading space; it could be handled in the regex, but if you are not 100% positive it's in all cases, then it might be simpler to add `trimws(.)`, as in

```r
strcapture('.*club_info="([^"]+),([^"]+)".(.*)', mystring, list(x1="", x2="", x3="")) |>
  lapply(trimws)
# $x1
# [1] "Elland Rd"
# $x2
# [1] "Leeds"
# $x3
# [1] "Pitch=\"100x50\""
```

In this case it does drop from a `data.frame` to a `list`, but I'm not certain you *need* a frame, a named list should suffice. If you really want it as a frame --- and many of my use-cases really prefer that --- just add `|> as.data.frame()` to the pipe.

Regex walk-through.

```
.*club_info="([^"]+),([^"]+)".(.*)
^^                                  leading/trailing text, discarded
  ^^^^^^^^^^^                       literal text
              [^"]+   [^"]+         one or more "any character except dquote"
             (     ),(     )        two capture-groups
```

Also, since we know that we'll have double quotes in the pattern and not single-quotes, I chose to use single-quotes as the outer string-defining demarcation. If we have *both* or if you want to avoid double-backslashes and the like, we can use R's "raw strings" instead,

```r
r"{.*club_info="([^"]+),([^"]+)".(.*)}"
```

where the `r"{` and `}"` are the open/close delimiters; I chose braces here since parens are visually confusing with the regex-parens, though brackets `r"[`/`]"` and parens `r"(`/`)"` also work.

Comment: Thanks, I've not heard of `strcapture` so this could be very useful. Just in terms of understanding my original string and an embedded double-quote would I gsub using `gsub('.*club_info="([^"]+),([^"]+)".(.*)', "\\2" mystring)` here? Assuming `[^"]+` is how we look for the first quotation mark?

Comment: @Joe, see my edit that includes a hint at the regex layout, does that answer your question?

Comment: sort of, I just can't seem to replicate it in a gsub, due to the quote and square brackets I think